# Calculate a case when count in a group by using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, case

i'm preatty beginner using python,
i'm trying to calculate the open rate ratio (a ration between two distinct count) in just one code line.
My dataframe is like this:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame([
    (142, 1, 'open' , 'Mobile'),
    (144, 2, 'open' , 'Mobile'),
    (144, 1, 'delivered', 'Web'),
    (142, 1, 'delivered', 'Mobile'),
    (142, 2, 'delivered', 'Web'),
    (144, 1, 'open', 'Web'),
    (142, 2, 'open', 'Mobile')
], columns=['sent_mail_id', 'customer_id', 'event' , 'Tool_used'])
```

I would like to calculate the open rate while grouping by the Column **Tool_used** Using Pandas.
In SQL Language would be this:

```
  select 
  Tool_used ,  
  count(distinct case when event='open' then sent_mail_id end)/count(distinct case when 
  event='delivered' then sent_mail_id end)
  from df
  group by 1
```

***Note that i would need to count distinctly the sent_mail_id since unique count is needed.***
Thank you

Comment: Would you please add some expected output layout ?   Would it be one column with 'open rate ratio' for each group ?    How's the `send_email_id` going to be displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), so then is necessary only divide columns `open` with `delivered` with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Tool_used'], df['event'])
print (df1)
event      delivered  open
Tool_used                 
Mobile             1     3
Web                2     1

df2 = df1['open'].div(df1['delivered']).reset_index(name='open rate ratio')
print (df2)
  Tool_used  open rate ratio
0    Mobile              3.0
1       Web              0.5
```

If need `groupby` compare and aggregate `sum`, but this is more complicated in my opinion:

```
a = (df['event'] == 'open').groupby(df['Tool_used']).sum()
b = (df['event'] == 'delivered').groupby(df['Tool_used']).sum()

df2 = a.div(b).reset_index(name='open rate ratio')
print (df2)
  Tool_used  open rate ratio
0    Mobile              3.0
1       Web              0.5
```

Solution with custom function (worse performance if big data):

```
def f(x):
    return (x == 'open').sum() / (x == 'delivered').sum()

df2 = df.groupby('Tool_used')['event'].agg(f).reset_index(name='open rate ratio')
print (df2)
  Tool_used  open rate ratio
0    Mobile              3.0
1       Web              0.5
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, is there a solution using a udf and applying it on the groupby?

Comment: @pellerossapelles - Do you think pyspark? Unfortunately not idea :(

Comment: No, i mean creating a function (that one with def statement) and using .apply() on the groupby. Sorry my language is really not tecnical

Comment: @pellerossapelles - Possible, but performance problem.

Comment: @pellerossapelles - Added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

See if this is what you need, with a column of `open rate ratio` within each group:

```
df1 = ((df.loc[df['event'] == 'open'].groupby('Tool_used')['event'].count() 
       / 
       df.loc[df['event'] == 'delivered'].groupby('Tool_used')['event'].count())
       .to_frame(name='open rate ratio')
      ).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)



  Tool_used  open rate ratio
0    Mobile              3.0
1       Web              0.5
```